# Google analytics data import via SFTP

Tags: google-analytics

I've been trying to import costs via SFTP, but I'm unable to get past `Create & generate key`. For testing purposes, I've created a SFTP server, and I'm able to connect to it from outside the network just fine, but when I pass the correct username & server url to the `Data import` settings, it just throws 500 without any further information.

Strange is that the Analytics are actually trying to connect to the SFTP server (I can see it through the logs) with the username `placeholder`, but they fail because of lack of public key - which they are supposed to give me AFTER `Create & generate key` button is pressed. Thanks for any advice.

[image: Analytics]

[image: sftp server logs]

**EDIT**:

Since Analytics are trying to connect to the server with [JSch](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/) library, I've tried to implement it my self, and it was able to successfully connect to the server. The main thing that bothers me is that google is for some reason trying to connect to the server without providing the key first and with wrong username as well. I've also found out, that others had the same problem, and already asked on the [google support](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/198456348/return-500-with-error-code-13-when-try-to-import-data-via-sftp?hl=en) - but without any response.

**EDIT 2**:

I've realized, that you should not provide username as part of the server URL - as stated in [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071301#join&zippy=%2Cverify-sftp-host-key-algorithms-format-sftp-server-url), but even if server URL without username is provided, it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your /etc/ssh/sshd_config add following lines.

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

Then restart service

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Issue is that in newer versions they removed ssh-rsa by default and Google Analytics still require it. There is no documentation about it so... enjoy :)

Also here is [Community Post about it](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/228448729/analytics-sftp-cost-import-will-end-up-with-error-500-code-13)

Comment: Yes, thats is the correct solution. To be honest, they actually do have it in their [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071301?hl=en#zippy=%2Cverify-sftp-host-key-algorithms-format-sftp-server-url).